# how to render image in gridview when adding the image from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to set image in first column in gridview from codebehind but the img tag is displaying as text not rendering as img

my code

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RdfDA DA = new RdfDA();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        List<Player> Players = DA.GetPlayers();

        dt.Columns.Add("Photo");
        dt.Columns.Add("PlayerName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Team");
        dt.Columns.Add("Result");
        dt.Columns.Add("Award");

        foreach(Player Player in Players)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                "<img href=\"" + Player.PlayerImg + "\"/>",
                Player.PlayerName,
                Player.PlayerTeam,
                Player.PlayerResult,
                Player.PlayerAward                                               
                });
        }

        GVPlayers.DataSource = dt;
        GVPlayers.DataBind();
    }
```

please any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `GridView` will have *HtmlEncode* set to *true*, which will do what you see and display HTML as text.

If you control these values, the easiest way for this is to set that to false in your GridView.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Photo" HeaderText="Photo" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

If you allow external input to the photo field, make sure you are sanitizing the input to prevent any attacks. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

> HTML-encoding field values helps to prevent cross-site scripting
>   attacks and malicious content from being displayed. This property
>   should be enabled whenever possible.

A more intuitive way for the front end code is to use a `TemplateField` and use that to control the HTML output.

Change your loop

```
dt.Rows.Add(Player.PlayerImg,
       Player.PlayerName,
       Player.PlayerTeam,
       Player.PlayerResult,
       Player.PlayerAward                                               
});
```

Then use this in your front code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Photo">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgPlayer" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Photo") %>' />                    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```